# captured row with a user's code in several columns. each column is task. I need to export each instance of the users code to another table

Tags: php, mysql

My row and headers look like this (Asignments Table):

```
Codigo|Tienda|Apertura|Cierre_20_00|Cierre_20_30|Cierre_21_00|Sanitarios|Barrer_Mat|Barrer_Vesp|Trapear_Mat|Trapear_Vesp|Limpiar_Ventanales_y_Vitrinas|Encargada|Supervisora

2     |1010  |2010    |0           |0           |2010        |3010      |3010      |2010       |2010       |3010        |3010                         |2010     |1102
```

Each task besides Codigo, Encargada and Supervisora has a user code asigned to it.
Now I need to export each instance for each task to another table where each task has specific timeframes to complete.
as in table Tareas (Tasks):

```
Asignacion |Tiempo_Inicio   |Tiempo_Limite  |Empleado   |Supervisor

Apertura   |11:00:00 AM     |11:10:00 AM    |           |
```

What code can I run after each Asignment capture is completed?
I believe it has to be an UPDATE, but how to pick each Assignment from that row and export it to each Empleado Column under Tasks table on SUBMIT?

Comment: **Apertura** is supposed to be the column or header of that table. Why do you use it in another table? Assign ids for foreign key.

Comment: Apertura is a Task. A store manager assigns all the tasks to employees  in the Assignment table. then the employee sees the individual TASK to complete individually from the Task table. Hence the same name.